# Probability of sampling at least one of each member of a set after n trials

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a bucket of balls $b_1, b_2, ... b_n$.

Each ball has uniform discrete probability $\frac{1}{n}$.

Suppose I am sampling balls with replacement. What is the probability I sample a certain sequence of balls, which does not have to be consecutive, by the $n$-th trial?

For example, let's say my sequence I care about is $b_1, b_3, b_2$.

If the trial outcomes are: $b_1, b_1, b_9, b_3, b_2$ then I have a success by the 5th trial.

Comment: Hi what have you tried for this exercise ?

Comment: The title and body of the question don't match.

Comment: An idea could be to maybe look at a random variable that models the total trials needed for the sequence to appear ($k$).
Now in your example $k\geq3$ of course and for each $k$ there are different options. Basically one could partition $k$ into sums of tree summands and each summand would represent the trials needed for one of the sequence members to appear. This is possible since the trials are independent and getting each sequence element can be seen as a new experiment basically. Then for each $k \geq3$ one would have to sum over all the possible partitions and the corresponding probabil.